# Why does OctoberCMS lack a visual editor Page & Post content?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

As a Content Management System I expected non-developers could edit Page content in a visual editor. I'm unclear why this was not included.

But Laravel and OctoberCMS is still slightly abstract for me, as I come from WordPress - like many.

Note, I am a programmer, not a front end user. But I build websites and applications for non-programmers.

Comment: I guess you should ask this question directly to main site's forum as author can answer you directly there. what you say? if you face any issue just post it here we can help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Content Management System is designed to programmer. The programmer can edit without a text editor or edit with the site in live server.

For non-programmer users we has another Plugins, like [Static Pages](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages). With this plugin the user has more tools to edit any content without coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins like [Wysiwyg Editors](https://octobercms.com/plugin/anandpatel-wysiwygeditors), [Static Pages](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages), and [Content Editor](https://octobercms.com/plugin/samuell-contenteditor) which can help bring your platform closer to WordPress. I have used one of these for numerous clients.

Though I have gotten to the point to where I have started making my own front end plugins that allow my clients to create, update, and delete pages. Add them to a menu etc. They can choose the layout, add sidebar(s) content and images. The plugins are all unique depending on what the client wants.

I think this is where OctoberCMS shines for developers and ultimately for your client. They don't need to be overwhelmed by everything in WordPress. You as a developer create a system (and hopefully foolproof it) that the client needs then hand it over to the client.